# Actualización de un registro especifico python + django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

He programado una view para crear/insertar artículos de forma satisfactoria, a continuación les coloco lo que ya tengo hecho:

```
def product_create_view(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ProductForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request,"products/product_create.html", context)
```

```
from django import forms

from .models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'price'
        ]
```

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Bien yo quiero poder actulizar un registro especifico, por ejemplo, si el usuario introduce el nombre del articulo "pera" entonces listame todo donde el nombre sea pera y que me permita modificarlo.

He estado buscando como hacer esto pero no logro dar con el asunto, he leído sobre la función filter() pero no lo pillo.

Sugerencias para lograrlo o ideas de donde encontrar información?

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/es

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una vista de lista para que te muestre los productos.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Product

class ProductsList(ListView):
    model = Products
    template_name = 'listaProductos.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['products'] = Product.objects.all()
        return context
```

Luego la urls.py

```
from .views import ProductList
# agregar en patterns
urlpatterns = [path('lista_productos', ProductsList.as_view(), name= 'listaProductos' ),]
```

y tu template >>> listaProductos.html

```
{% for item in products %}
<p> {{item.propiedad}} </p> # propiedad serian los campos del modelo p.e: item.precio
{% enfor %}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, pero lo he probado y no me ha funcionado, sin embargo he conseguido la respuesta.

Comment: Genial!!! Debes probad las vistas basadas en clases. Es la verdadera  genialidad de django. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias a quienes intentaron brindarme una solución.

He encontrado la respuesta, espero que les funcione a todos los que busquen ejemplos de insertar, eliminar y editar registros.

[Aquí](https://rayed.com/posts/2018/05/django-crud-create-retrieve-update-delete/)

Saludos,